# I have an SSD installed on a mac I do not use, how do I use it on another desktop?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd

Do I have to format an SSD from OS X in order to re-use it on an Windows desktop?
Or Is there no limitations to where to format the drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question:
No it doesn't matter from which OS you're formatting the drive to a specific file system. File systems are standardized and any reliable OS should do the job well.
The OS just need to support the file system.

That said - question number two:
Windows requires NTFS which is not fully supported under OSX (in fact you're only able to read from NTFS, but can't write any data on it).
So you won't be able to format the disk on OSX for Windows without any third party software, adding the appropriate support for NTFS (I've been used to had that software, since I had to deal with both OS. I can't remember the name, but it wasn't for free).

Don't worry about the lack of NTFS on OSX. During the Windows installer process, you'll be able to reformat the SSD to NTFS.

Comment: I was wondering whether Windows would allow me to format the drive not formatted in NTFS format, however it did using diskmgmt.msc util. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to a standard 2.5" form factor SATA SSD drive then it should be able to be used elsewhere, internally on another system or in an external enclosure, supporting the same form factor. As to partitioning/formatting, if the target OS is Windows then I'd partition/format it under Windows.